# Turning a value in an JSON array into contents of a downloadable pdf by jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, jspdf

I am quite new to js and want to turn a value inside an json array into contents of a downloadable pdf

like:

```
 <div class="container">                   
        <input  type="button" value="Create PDF"               
                onclick="generatePDF()">
    </div>
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const data = {
            "squadName": "Super hero squad",
            "homeTown": "Metro City",
            "formed": 2016,
            "secretBase": "Super tower",
            "active": true
        }
        const pdfvalue = tree[1];

        function generatePDF() {
            const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
            const doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.text(pdfvalue, 100, 100);
            doc.save("newFile.pdf");               
        }           
    </script>
```

I just want to put "Metro City" only into the PDF, but it says invalid arguments passed to jsPDF, is there any way that i could do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you're trying to access tree[1], but there is no tree variable defined. Instead, you should access the value from the data object directly. Here's an updated version of your code that should work:

```
<div class="container">                   
    <input type="button" value="Create PDF" onclick="generatePDF()">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const data = {
        "squadName": "Super hero squad",
        "homeTown": "Metro City",
        "formed": 2016,
        "secretBase": "Super tower",
        "active": true
    };
    const pdfvalue = data.homeTown;

    function generatePDF() {
        const doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.text(pdfvalue, 10, 10);
        doc.save("newFile.pdf");               
    }           
</script>
```